# It is harder for users to log on to my website when using gmails "+company" email address feature. How can I help them?

Tags: email, authentication, email-address, accounts

If you have a website and lots of people create his accounts with this format:

```
mail+mycompanysite@gmail.com
mail+companysite@gmail.com
mail+company_site@gmail.com
```

This issue is causing me several problems.

1. people forgot they append `+mycompanysite` and can't login
2. people can't recover password for the same reason above (email not registered)

How am I supposed to handle this situation?

Answer (score 1):

You could include the email encrypted in a cookie to help recover the account easily.

As far as I know, if you send an email to mail+company_site@gmail.com it will be received at mail@gmail.com so you can use this option to recover the account. For example, if you check that someone is trying to log in with:

- mail+wrong1@gmail.com
- mail+wrong2@gmail.com
- mail+wrong3@gmail.com

Automatically you could send an email to mail@gmail.com with the actual email account (mail+correct@gmail.com) as a reminder in case they forgot the log-in data.

Comment: So, it's not easier if I remove always all words after plus sign when login in or recover password?

Comment: As a user, I don't like to be restricted, but obviously, that's an option.

Comment: I mean, an user can set mail+mycompanysite@gmail.com, but I only use mail@gmail.com when doing login / recover pass validation. What do you think?
 Looks good for me, for the user is something "under the hood".